# How to check for contents of a loaded div tag using jquery load?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, onchange

I'm working with jqueries address change event and am hitting a roadblock when a user copies and pastes a URL in the browser.  I need to fist load a portion of the page that contains a form.  I could do this after every pagination call but it seems really ineffecient.

Here is my current code block:

```
$.address.change(function(e) {

    var urlAux = e.value.split('=');
    var page   = urlAux[0];
    var start  = urlAux[1];

    if (page == "/visits") {

        $.address.title("Profile Views");

        if (start) {

            $('#start').val(start);

            // ***** If a user has copied and pasted this URL with a start value then I first need to load visits.php in the main div tag.  Is it possible to see if this is loaded or not?

            $.post("visits_results.php", $("#profile_form_id").serialize(),
                function(data) {
                    $('#search_results').html(data);
                    location.href = "#visits=" + start; 
                });

        }
        else {
            var args = localStorage.getItem("visits");

            $('#main').load("visits.php?" + args, function () { }); 
        }
    }
```

My attempted work around was this:

```
var args = localStorage.getItem("visits");

$('#main').load("visits.php?" + args, function () { 

    $('#start').val(start);

    $.post("visits_results.php", $("#profile_form_id").serialize(),
        function(data) {
            $('#search_results').html(data);
            location.href = "#visits=" + start; 
         });
    });
```

There must be a better way...this is realoading the same portion of the page (visits.php) with every pagination event. Is there a better way to load URLs and not have them trigger an address change?

Comment: I'm not sure what your overall goal is.  It sounds like you have formatted html / form data on 'visits.php' that you always need, but I'm guessing including the page when it's blank looks tacky. that sum it up?

Comment: visits.php is just a form that when posted returns it's results to another div tag on the page.  The pagination controls are part of the visits.php page.  The issue is if I'm required to load the visits.php portion of the page after every page change the pagaination controls are "flashing" as they get loaded each and every time.  I'm able to load the form once but this fails if a user enters a url directly in the browser.  I need a way to either detect this and load the visits.php form just once or determine if it's already loaded. Any thoughts?

Comment: After a bit more hacking I came up with this solution that seems to do the trick.  I'm not sure how good it is but it seems to do the trick.  I now get the main div id and do a regex match on a unique string in the form.  If I don't see it I load the form and then load the results. Not sure if this is good practice or not but it seems to solve my issue.

Comment: Same idea as yours, but take a look at jQuery [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data).  You can attach something as simple as "{"hasVisitsPhp":"it's loaded"}" to your '#mainDiv'.  if the flag is there, then you're golden.  If it's not, do your work.  This would not depend on page html content.

Comment: Great solution!  Can you post that as your answer so I can give you credit :) Thanks, -Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using paul's work around from his comments, but instead of Regex'ing html content in the visits.php form this solution will look for data() attached to #mainID.

Paul's work around notes:

> After a bit more hacking I came up with this solution that seems to do
>   the trick. I'm not sure how good it is but it seems to do the trick. I
>   now get the main div id and do a regex match on a unique string in the
>   form. If I don't see it I load the form and then load the results. Not
>   sure if this is good practice or not but it seems to solve my issue.

Methodology to use .data() instead of a regex search of visits.php's html:

```
    /*check if we're missing visits.php by looking for data() flag*/
             if( !($("#main").data()["hasVisitsPhp"]) ){
              var args = localStorage.getItem("visits");
              $('#main').load("visits.php?" + args, function () { 
                $('#start').val(start);
                $.post("visits_results.php", $("#profile_form_id").serialize(),
                    function(data) {
/* we've loaded visits.php, set the data flag on #main*/
                $('#main').data("hasVisitsPhp","loaded");
                        $('#search_results').html(data);
                        location.href = "#visits=" + start; 
                     });
                });
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

try `window.location.hash` instead. Changing the whole href can/will trigger a whole-page reload, while changing just the hash by itself should at most cause the page to scroll.

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately the #main div tag gets loaded each and every time becuase the URL changes each time (start=x, x being the page number) This is only an issue when a user copies the URL in the browser with a page number included. I'd like for them to be taken directly to the page. Can I avoid triggering the address change event is a user calls a URL directly?

Comment: "directly"? As in enters a url into the address bar by typing or cut/paste?

Comment: directly as a user copies the URL into the browser like so: http://localhost/menu.php?home#visits=20